# Power expansion for the square root of an even degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am reading an article from 1936 with something that looks like an easy way to solve Riccati equations with variable coefficients as nice polynomials.The link is : http://www.jstor.org/stable/2301168?seq=2 . The problem is that at page 474 the author talks about some power expansion of square root of an even degree polynomial and even though he gives two examples I don't really understand what is he really doing. Could someone explain me or at least give me a hint on this?
So, you have a polynomial P(x) which is of even degree but not necessarily in a nice form (you can't make a square ) . Now you take the square root of this polynomial and you try to approximate it with a decreasing power expansion.This is what I don't get, how do you do that (and what results let you do that). For example,

$$
P(x) = x^{6}+8x^{4}-x^{3}+7x-2,
$$

The expansion(or in his words"the polynomial part of the expansion in series of descending powers of x") of the $\sqrt{P(x)}$ is given in the article as $x^{3}+7x-\frac{1}{2}$. Does anyone know how did he got there? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "descending powers of $x$", it means an expansion of the form

$$
\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} a_ix^{-i}
$$
where $n$ can be any positive or negative integer (if the polynomial was of odd degree, then it would require $\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} a_ix^{\frac{1}{2}-i}$). So if we look at the polynomial again, you have

$$
\sqrt{P(x)} = \sqrt{x^6+8x^4−x^3+7x−2} = x^3\sqrt{1+8x^{-2}-x^{-3}+7x^{-5}-2x^{-6}}
$$
We can now perform a taylor expansion on $X=8x^{-2}-x^{-3}+7x^{-5}-2x^{-6}$, so we have $\sqrt{1+X}$.

$$
\sqrt{1+X} \approx 1+\frac{X}{2}+O(X^2)
$$
This gives

$$
\sqrt{P(x)} \approx x^3+4x-\frac{1}{2} + O(x^{-1})
$$
Note that I believe that either you've mis-copied the approximation given in the article, or the article had a typo. It should not be $x^3+7x-\frac{1}{2}$, as the square of that is

$$
(x^3+7x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = x^6 + 14x^4-x^3+49x^2-7x+\frac{1}{4}
$$
which is clearly *not* a good approximation to $P(x)$. By comparison

$$
(x^3+4x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = x^6 + 8x^4-x^3+16x^2-4x+\frac{1}{4}
$$
which agrees with $P(x)$ in the first three terms, and thus is a good approximation for large $x$.

Comment: Is indeed 4 not 7. Great explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this. In the same article there was another example  with $P(x)=x^{4}-2x^{3}+x-6$ . I found that the approximation  $\sqrt{P(x)}\approx {x^{2}-x}$. The article gives the approximation $\sqrt{P(x)}\approx{x^{2}-x-\frac{1}{2}}$ . Am I wrong or there is a typo in the article?

Comment: $(x^2-x)^2=x^4-2x^3+x^2$, while $(x^2-x-\frac12)^2=x^4-2x^3+x-\frac14$. The article is correct.

Comment: Your confusion may be coming from the fact that the expansion I gave for $\sqrt{1+X}$ was only as long as it needed to be for the original question. To the next order, it's $\sqrt{1+X}=1+\frac{X}{2}-\frac{X^2}{8}+O(X^3)$. See here for more terms: http://planetmath.org/taylorexpansionofsqrt1x

Answer (score 1):

Given an even-degree polynomial $$P(x) = a_{2n} x^{2n} + a_{2n-1} x^{2n-1} + \ldots + a_0 = x^{2n} (a_{2n} + a_{2n-1} x^{-1} + \ldots + a_0 x^{-2n}) = a_{2n} x^{2n} (1 + f(1/x)) $$
(where $f(t) = O(t)$ as $t \to 0$) we can write
$$ \sqrt{P(x)} = a_{2n}^{1/2} x^n (1 + f(1/x))^{1/2} = a_{2n}^{1/2} x^n 
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k+1}{4}^{-k} \left( 2
\,k \right) !\,{f(1/x)}^{k}}{ \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,k-1
 \right) }}$$
For the "polynomial part", we keep only the terms that end up with a nonnegative power of $x$.
In the example given, $n=3$, $a_6 = 1$ and $f(1/x) = 8 x^{-2} - x^{-3} + \ldots$ so
$$ \sqrt{P(x)} = x^3 \left( 1 + \left(\frac{4}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2x^3}+\ldots\right)+\ldots\right)
= x^3 + 4 x - \frac{1}{2} + \ldots $$

Comment: Professor Robert Israel, what is the reference of the formulation you have given here?